# Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have changed database from [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), but I don't know how to transfer data from one to other.

Does anyone know any command by which I can copy/migrate my database from [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)?

Comment: Pivotal also released a tool: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pg2mysql (same name as the script below - different features though).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Faced the problem a few years ago, and used **[pg2mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php)**

**EDIT 21 july 2019** : **[this fork](https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/pg2mysql)** seems a better option (patches, light maintenance)

Comment: In my case it has not worked well in converting the `COPY` commands that are produced by exporting from postgres.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese Using --inserts option dump data as INSERT commands.

Comment: script has syntax errors everywhere (MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 12.04). Works about as well as following [these instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-linux.html)

Comment: If you're using php 7 you'll get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in pg2mysql.inc.php on line 133` fix it either by removing the `&` (pass by reference in function calls) for all errors in the source or easily run `php5 pg2mysql_cli.php <inputfilename.sql> <outputfilename.sql> [engine]` in the command line if available

Comment: Unfortunately this trick will fail on large DBs. I use a soft called "PostgreSQL to MySQL" (https://www.convert-in.com/pgs2sql.htm) for years myself. It works like a charm, even on huge databases, but comes at a cost: $49. Otherwise answer by @CarstenSchmitz below is the best solution IMO.

Comment: This sucks, all kinds of syntax errors when converting postgres to msyql.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) which can import from a variety of database types, including Postgres.

Comment: Sadly it does not work in macOS Sierra as of now.

Comment: But available only for mysql workbench commercial users.

Comment: @caras That's not true. MySQL workbench import works in the standard version just fine.

Comment: Here is the direct HowTo link to Migrate PostgreSQL databases to MySQL using the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard: https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/

Comment: Trying to install on MAC, the new  version would not work since my MAC was not updated to 10.4, older version will not start installing, will not even give you a message on why it's not starting, it's terrible, use Dbeaver instead, I got it working in 5 mins.

Comment: On Windows with Workbench 8.0.20, it was just too buggy. DBeaver is much better and more reliable.

Answer (score 5):

[Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) is the perfect solution for painless migration, column to column mapping, character encoding and also open source.

Comment: Definitely a nice tool! Nothing "painless" about that migration, though.. at least not in my case. The column mapping alone took too much manual work since the automatic types it chooses aren't very good...

Comment: So... how is this done in DBeaver? Specifically, copying the table data structures, and separately, copying the data. Can you explain the process in your answer? For copying the data, I can only find how to do 1 table at a time, which is really inefficient.

Comment: Dbeaver is great, installed easily on MAC, super-intuitive and prompted me to install the mysql/postgres drivers. Works flawlessly!