# Convert a PostgreSQL dump into a MySQL dump

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-restore, database-dump

I have a Postgres dump file and I need to turn it into a MySQL dump so I can create a matching MySQL database. I am new to Postgres I have it installed on my Ubuntu server and I was going to see whether I could import and export SQL of some sort.  I don't know how to do that.

Here is the command I tried:

```sh
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U dbuser testdb > b526.dump
```

This doesn't error but I don't think anything happened:

```
testdb=# \dt;
No relations found.
testdb=# \d
No relations found.
testdb=# \t
Showing only tuples.
testdb=# \d
```

Also, I would appreciate an easier way to turn this .dump into a MySQL dump.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql

Comment: Many [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+[mysql]+migrate+convert&submit=search).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the data of the PostgreSQL database in plain text format with `-Fp` (plain), but you will have to do some manual conversion afterwards, since PostgreSQL contains many non-standard extensions to the SQL language.

However, if you already converted the schema, a data dump should be mostly compatible.

I recommend to use a tool like [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/). It supports conversions from one database to another.

Comment: What *many* non-standard extensions are you referring to? In my experience MySQL is a lot more non-standard than PostgreSQL

Comment: Look through http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-commands.html, and see the Compatibility notes in each section.

Comment: Can you provide a link as to how to do these conversions? I installed SQL Squirrel and set it up, but am having a hard time finding any info on converting a database.

Comment: Edit: need to use the DBCopy plugin, it turns out. Right-click all tables in the schema, hit copy, go to the other session and paste into the tables section for your db.

Comment: Sorry for triple comment, but the DBCopy plugin's migration functionality is incredibly fragile. It can't handle converting to / from postgres' citext datatype, among numerous other things. I kinda regret spending time on this. Hopefully there's a better tool for SquirrelSQL.

Comment: Please note that citext is a extension to postgresql and not part of the PostgreSQL core functionality.