# How to migrate database from Postgres to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I want to convert some tables from a Postgres database to MySQL. Ideally I would like to create an script that would convert the tables for PG to MySQL, but I am glad if we are able to figure out how to make it possible in a not-scriptable way.

First of all, I have read a similar post here: [Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql)

I have tried both solutions proposed there, but they did't make the trick.

It's important to say that **I want to migrate the structure and the data.**

But first things first, here is the SQL dump of the postgres-database:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0; SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'; SET standard_conforming_strings = off; SET check_function_bodies = false; SET client_min_messages = warning; SET escape_string_warning = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: grupos; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE grupos (
    "dirGrupo" text,
    valor real,
    "flagIntelli" boolean DEFAULT false,
    "flagQDS" boolean DEFAULT false,
    finalidad text,
    "idGrupo" integer DEFAULT nextval('"idGrupo"'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "claseDomo" text,
    instalado boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
    "codCasa" "char",
    "codUnidad" integer,
    protocolo text NOT NULL,
    escritura boolean,
    dispositivo text,
    "tipoDatos" oid,
    "coordX" integer DEFAULT (-1),
    "coordY" integer DEFAULT (-1),
    mapa text,
    "reglasAsociadas" text );


ALTER TABLE public.grupos OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Data for Name: grupos; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'sensor', 10, 'LightSensor', true, 'E', 1, 'x10', false, 'SensorLum1', 7, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'luz', 11, 'SimpleLamp', true, 'K', 1, 'x10', true, 'Luz4', 1, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'Radiador de la sala', 298, 'Heater', true, 'B', 1, 'x10', true, 'RadiadorX10', 1, 163, 168, 'Sala Quercus', '108;111;115;117;119;123;127;131;134;136;138;140;144;148;150;152;155;157;159;162;166;169;172;176;179;182;185;188;190;193;196;199;201;205;209;214;218;222;226;230;234;238;250;254;260;264;277;278;279;280;284;293;297;301;305;309;313;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/5', 1, false, false, 'Interruptor', 213, 'Button', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Interruptor', 1, 301, 326, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/4', 0, false, false, 'Enchufe4', 316, 'Switch', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Enchufe4', 1, 303, 133, 'Plano Casa', '268;272;276;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/2', 0, false, false, 'Enchufe2', 210, 'Switch', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Enchufe2', 1, 141, 322, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/1', 0, false, false, 'LuzFlexo', 217, 'SimpleLamp', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzFlexo', 1, 80, 45, 'Plano Casa', '267;271;275;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/3', 1, false, false, 'Router', 221, 'Router', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Router1', 1, 467, 439, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/6', 21.68, false, false, 'SensorTemperatura', 237, 'TemperatureSensor', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', false, 'SensorTemperatura', 2, 146, 436, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'SensorX10', 219, 'MotionSensor', true, 'A', 1, 'x10', false, 'SensorX10', 6, 362, 11, 'Plano Casa', '335;336;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/5', 1, false, false, '', 12, 'MotionSensor', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', false, 'SensorPresencia', 6, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/2', 50, false, true, 'Luz Intervalo', 248, 'DimmableLight', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzHInt', 3, 97, 276, 'Plano Casa', '265;269;273;338;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/1', 0, false, false, 'LuzHBin', 215, 'SimpleLamp', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzHBin', 1, 357, 189, 'Plano Casa', '266;270;274;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 1, false, true, 'Encender la luz del flexo', 291, 'SimpleLamp', true, 'C', 1, 'x10', true, 'BombillaX10', 1, 272, 130, 'Sala Quercus', '107;109;110;112;113;114;116;118;120;121;122;124;125;126;128;129;130;132;133;135;137;139;141;142;143;145;146;147;149;151;153;154;156;158;160;161;163;164;165;167;168;170;171;173;174;175;177;178;180;181;183;184;186;187;189;191;192;194;195;197;198;200;202;203;204;206;207;208;210;211;212;213;215;216;217;219;220;221;223;224;225;227;228;229;231;232;233;235;236;237;239;240;249;251;252;253;255;256;257;258;259;261;262;263;281;282;283;290;291;292;294;295;296;298;299;300;302;303;304;306;307;308;310;311;312;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;335;336;');


--
-- Name: grupos_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY grupos
    ADD CONSTRAINT grupos_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("idGrupo");


--
-- Name: grupos_tipoDatos_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY grupos
    ADD CONSTRAINT "grupos_tipoDatos_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("tipoDatos") REFERENCES "TiposDatos"(id);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

**1) First approach, Using pG2Mysql**: http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php
Simple and fast (in theory): Unfortunately it has several errors when parsing:

Here is the document retrieved:

```
# Converted with pg2mysql-1.9
# Converted on Mon, 22 Apr 2013 14:12:28 -0400
# Lightbox Technologies Inc. http://www.lightbox.ca

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET time_zone="+00:00";

CREATE TABLE grupos (
    `dirGrupo` text,
    valor real,
    `flagIntelli` bool DEFAULT 0,
    `flagQDS` bool DEFAULT 0,
    finalidad text,
    `idGrupo` int(11) auto_increment NOT NULL,
    `claseDomo` text,
    instalado bool DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    `codCasa` `char`,
    `codUnidad` int(11),
    protocolo text NOT NULL,
    escritura bool,
    dispositivo text,
    `tipoDatos` oid,
    `coordX` int(11) DEFAULT -1 ,
    `coordY` int(11) DEFAULT -1 ,
    mapa text,
    `reglasAsociadas` text , PRIMARY KEY(`idGrupo`) ) TYPE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'sensor', 10, 'LightSensor', true, 'E', 1, 'x10', false, 'SensorLum1', 7, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'luz', 11, 'SimpleLamp', true, 'K', 1, 'x10', true, 'Luz4', 1, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'Radiador de la sala', 298, 'Heater', true, 'B', 1, 'x10', true, 'RadiadorX10', 1, 163, 168, 'Sala Quercus', '108;111;115;117;119;123;127;131;134;136;138;140;144;148;150;152;155;157;159;162;166;169;172;176;179;182;185;188;190;193;196;199;201;205;209;214;218;222;226;230;234;238;250;254;260;264;277;278;279;280;284;293;297;301;305;309;313;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;315;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/5', 1, false, false, 'Interruptor', 213, 'Button', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Interruptor', 1, 301, 326, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/4', 0, false, false, 'Enchufe4', 316, 'Switch', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Enchufe4', 1, 303, 133, 'Plano Casa', '268;272;276;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/2', 0, false, false, 'Enchufe2', 210, 'Switch', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Enchufe2', 1, 141, 322, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/1', 0, false, false, 'LuzFlexo', 217, 'SimpleLamp', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzFlexo', 1, 80, 45, 'Plano Casa', '267;271;275;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/3', 1, false, false, 'Router', 221, 'Router', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'Router1', 1, 467, 439, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('0/0/6', 21.68, false, false, 'SensorTemperatura', 237, 'TemperatureSensor', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', false, 'SensorTemperatura', 2, 146, 436, 'Plano Casa', NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 0, false, false, 'SensorX10', 219, 'MotionSensor', true, 'A', 1, 'x10', false, 'SensorX10', 6, 362, 11, 'Plano Casa', '335;336;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/5', 1, false, false, '', 12, 'MotionSensor', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', false, 'SensorPresencia', 6, -1, -1, NULL, NULL); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/2', 50, false, true, 'Luz Intervalo', 248, 'DimmableLight', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzHInt', 3, 97, 276, 'Plano Casa', '265;269;273;338;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES ('1/1/1', 0, false, false, 'LuzHBin', 215, 'SimpleLamp', true, NULL, NULL, 'knx', true, 'LuzHBin', 1, 357, 189, 'Plano Casa', '266;270;274;'); INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (NULL, 1, false, true, 'Encender la luz del flexo', 291, 'SimpleLamp', true, 'C', 1, 'x10', true, 'BombillaX10', 1, 272, 130, 'Sala Quercus', '107;109;110;112;113;114;116;118;120;121;122;124;125;126;128;129;130;132;133;135;137;139;141;142;143;145;146;147;149;151;153;154;156;158;160;161;163;164;165;167;168;170;171;173;174;175;177;178;180;181;183;184;186;187;189;191;192;194;195;197;198;200;202;203;204;206;207;208;210;211;212;213;215;216;217;219;220;221;223;224;225;227;228;229;231;232;233;235;236;237;239;240;249;251;252;253;255;256;257;258;259;261;262;263;281;282;283;290;291;292;294;295;296;298;299;300;302;303;304;306;307;308;310;311;312;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;314;316;317;335;336;'); ALTER TABLE grupos
    ADD CONSTRAINT grupos_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("idGrupo");
```

When I import this file to the database using any Database Manager I recieve nothing but errors:

[image: The first error]

For some reason the parser marks *chars* between those symbols: ''.
If we look carefully, sometimes the names of the columns are between  ''  and other times not, why?

I delete those symbols around *char* and proceed to do the same import again, but again another error faces up:

[image: The second error]

Type oid? what is that? Reading I see that is a type used for primary keys.

**2) Second approach, I will try with [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/):**

I installed this feature in Ubuntu and I gave it a try. There is an option to migrate databases, great!

1.- I introduce the source and test the connection:

[image: The source connection test]

2.- Then the Destination and test the connection:

[image: The destination connection test]

3.- The next screen, everything is ok:

[image: Things are working]

4.- Now I am asked to select the Schema, I select the default option:

[image: Select the schema]

5.- And I receive the following error, failing in the point named, "Reverse engineer selected schemata".

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting...
Connecting to postgresql@DRIVER=Postgresql;SERVER=158.49.245.68;PORT=5432...
Opening ODBC connection to DRIVER=Postgresql;SERVER=158.49.245.68;PORT=5432;DATABASE=QDSDatabase;UID=postgres...
Connected
Connect to source DBMS done
Reverse engineer selected schemata....
Reverse engineering public from QDSDatabase
- Reverse engineering catalog information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 335, in reverseEngineer
    return PostgresqlReverseEngineering.reverseEngineer(connection, catalog_name, schemata_list, context)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 207, in reverseEngineer
    catalog = cls.reverseEngineerCatalog(connection, catalog_name)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 367, in reverseEngineerCatalog
    cls.reverseEngineerSequences(connection, schema)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 76, in reverseEngineerSequences
    min_value, max_value, start_value, increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, ncache = cls.execute_query(connection, seq_details_query % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 56, in execute_query
    return cls.get_connection(connection_object).cursor().execute(query, *args, **kwargs)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42P01', '[42P01] ERROR: no existe la relaci\xc3\xb3n \xc2\xabpublic.idtipodatos\xc2\xbb;\nError while executing the query (7) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_schema_selection.py", line 160, in task_reveng
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration.py", line 332, in reverseEngineer
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
SystemError: ProgrammingError("('42P01', '[42P01] ERROR: no existe la relaci\xc3\xb3n \xc2\xabpublic.idtipodatos\xc2\xbb;\nError while executing the query (7) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemata: ProgrammingError("('42P01', '[42P01] ERROR: no existe la relaci\xc3\xb3n \xc2\xabpublic.idtipodatos\xc2\xbb;\nError while executing the query (7) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed
```

6.- If I try with other type of schemas (POINT 4.-) the program closes suddenly :

[image: Exit(-1)]

That's all, I have tried this in several ways with Mysql Workbench, which seemed great, but unfortunately nothing worked.

Any ideas? Remember that the postgres SQL is in the beginning of the post, so anyone can try the migration.

Comment: Well, that's a nice story, but the solutions are already well established: Do a schema dump and then per-table dumps to CSV. Hand convert the schema and load it into MySQL, then import the data into each table. If you don't like that approach you can use ETL tools like Pentaho Kettle or Talend Studio to do the data migration. Schema conversion tools also exist, but usually cost $. The one thing **absolutely guaranteed not to work** is to just dump the DB and try to load it into MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to avoid the Schema conversion by hand. As Richar Huxton commented I really don't understand PostgreSQL & MySQL deep enough to do it properly. But honestly I think I don't have other chance but to try it.

Comment: Cannot answer as this is closed, but you should learn SQL first. If you don't want to, try one of the other automatic tools: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL or try [Pentaho Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/).

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be difficult for you I'm afraid.

1. You don't seem to understand PostgreSQL
2. You don't seem to understand MySQL
3. You don't seem to understand your database schema

If that is your entire schema, just copy it into your text editor of choice and manually update it.

What the "oid" column is being used for I couldn't say, but it's nothing to do with a primary key (perhaps a large object or "blob"?).

The quoting is used only where you've used mixed-case identifies LikeThis. By default SQL is case-insensitive.

Mysql doesn't have a real "boolean" type, you'll probably want to use `bit` or `tinyint`.

The nextval() call in the schema is to generate unique ids. This is a PostgreSQL thing and not supported in MySQL - you'll probably want an auto_increment modifier.

Between those tips and the pg2mysql output that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to parse the Schema and pass the data from one to another database in CSV format in order to make it scriptable.

I coulnd't tell you why the oid is used there. I didn't design the database schema, but I am afraid the designer didn't know neither :)

Thanks for the quotes and boolean tips!

Comment: @Jesus "oid" is an internal column in old (`WITH OIDS`) PostgreSQL tables. It's still used in system catalogs but not much else normally. It's very unlikely that you use it for anything and it can generally be omitted when doing data migrations. "oid" is "object identifier". See the PostgreSQL docs for all the details.