# changing database from PostgreSQL to MySQL in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

In my current application i am using PostgreSQL Data base,

but I want to change the PostgreSQL database into MYSQL DB.

if it's impossible ?

Comment: is there data to migrate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1**

Make a backup copy of your data

For Rails 3, install the YAML DB gem: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

For Rails 2.x install the YAML DB plugin:

script/plugin install git://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db.git

Run the dump task

rake db:dump

**Step 2**

Update your config/database.yml file.

**Step 3 :**

gem install mysql

Have rake create your database

rake db:create

rake db:schema:load

**Step 4**

Use YamlDb to reload your data into MySql

rake db:load

Comment: How to run on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

this is a duplicate

[Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql)

dont forget to change the gems and your database config file to something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```