# migrating rails app from postgresql to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm attempting to migrate my rails application from postgresql to mySQL so as to view the data in one place within xampp in PHPmyadmin. The reason is the fact that I need to access the data that is located within the MySQL database from my rails app which is in postgresql.

As of now most questions I found aim to create a new application within mySQL with rails but I need to migrate all of the data my current rails application compatible and use MySQL.

Is there a proper process and simple procedure that allows for this migration from postgresql to mySQL?

Note: MySQL is within xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql)

got the answer to your question.

It's very easy, just paste your postgres dump in [this website](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php) and you'll get the same dump converted in mysql, ready for you to be imported.

Then you will just need to properly configure your database.yml and you're set.