# Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL with JSON fields

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql

I want to migrate a postgres DB that uses JSONB fields to a MySQL DB with the new JSON fields.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql) was answered for databases without json - but both solutions don't support json fields

Comment: it does now (a relatively recent edition)

Comment: [MySQL just added a JSON data type in 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). Without more information about your use of JSON I can't say much more than to use at least 5.7.8. With a feature that brand new (they're only on 5.7.9) I'd be wary.

Comment: I use the latest version, that does indeed support json fields. but the migration tools (including the one in workbench) don't support it.