# Import basehansard.sql.bz2 into MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, bz2, mysql-error-1193

How can I import basehansard.sql.bz2 into MySQL? I tried extracting the file so that it was basehansard.sql (text file), but the data import still had an error (ERROR 1193 "Unknown system variable 'statement_timeout'").

The data source is http://www.lipad.ca/data/. I'm using Workbench 6.3 CE.

Comment: You can't import PostgreSQL into MySQL. They're two different languages. You could install Postgres, import it, then re-export it to a common format like CSV, and then import that into MySQL.

Comment: Maybe a search for "convert postgresql to mysql" might help, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5909223/1741542